# Why would domdocument load work on dev sie but give an error on production?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am stumped. The code is exactly the same and they are both hosted by the same rackspace . . . yet one works fine and the other generates an error:

> [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

The code is fairly simple:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$page_url = **valid XML feed**
$doc->load($page_url);
```

So I do not understand what is causing the error . . . Any ideas on what to check?

---

Also: everything was working fine until yesterday - so it must have been something in one of the (unfortunately very numerous) patches implemented yesterday. Just need an Idea of where to start looking

---

Some investigating reveals it is the feed's problem - (Indeed's job API) - switched to a different job feed provider & everything is working, still confused why it would work in dev but not production (unless indeed blocked us for some reason)

Comment: It's a long shot but the difference in production/dev could relate to a cached DNS entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem: IP address was being blocked by the api provider . . . thanks for the advice anyways.

Answer (score 1):

URL wrappers on your system might be disabled. Please can you check the value of the PHP ini variable `allow_url_fopen`? If it's disabled you won't be allowed to fetch files from URLs.

```
echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

Comment: Can you try `echo file_get_content($page_url)` please and see if you get a similar error from that?

Comment: Can you open the DTD URL in a web browser from your workstation? Would suggest using `echo($page_url)` to be 100% sure.

Comment: The url is given in the error, and it loads just fine. Loads fine on the dev site as well - I have checked an they are the same.

Comment: If you have console (SSH) access to the server can you try `wget http://path/to/your/url` (with your URL in there!) and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php#91384

> **Jonas Due Vesterheden  09-Jun-2009 03:18**
>   I had a problem with loading documents over HTTP. I would get errors looking like this:
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://external/document.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The document would load fine in browsers and using wget. The problem is that DOMDocument::load() on my systems (both OS X and Linux) didn't send any User-Agent header which for some weird reason made Microsoft-IIS/6.0 respond with the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a remote feed (not on a machine local to each server) then chances are it's due to something related with allow_url_fopen.  Usually loading files remotely as if they were a local resource is disabled for security reasons.